# How to make .NET WebForm Routing work with Authorization

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, .net-4.0, routes, webforms

I have routes that are being registered from the database into an asp.net website (non MVC).  The routes register fine, they all work when I am logged in.  What I am trying to do is create a landing page based on some route data:

Page is [site]/landing/dell

The route looks like: "landing/{client}" and it routes to my page Login.aspx, in there I get the client out of the route, then display some custom brand data based on the value.

In my web.config, I have my authentication mode set to forms, with my loginUrl = "Login.aspx"

When the user does not have the authorization cookie, it redirects the user to:

[site]/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2flanding%2fdell instead of keeping the route url, and displaying the correct data.  The IIS server actually does not even process the route at all, just sends the user to the Login.aspx page.

I have tried several additions to my web.config: 
`<location path="landing"><system.web><authorization><allow users="*"/></auth></sys.web></loc>` etc, and many variations, but nothing seems to work.

Ideas anyone?  I assume this is a common issue, and it is just not well documented.

Comment: As a workaround currently I evaluate the Request.QueryString["ReturlUrl"] value and do some stuff, but that is no good.  It will enable me to get the work done however until a solution is found.  Still open to ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally figured it out.  I am going to try and explain this in a simple form, in hopes that it will one day help somebody else.

Several things here to remember, first, it is a non MVC app, purely webforms.

In my Global.ascx, there is a method:

```
    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Add(new Route("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));
        routes.Add(new Route("{service}.asmx/{*pathInfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));
        routes.Add(new Route("*.psd/{*pathinfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));
        routes.Add(new Route("*.js/{*pathinfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));
        routes.Add(new Route("*.jpg/{*pathinfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));
        routes.Add(new Route("*.gif/{*pathinfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));
        routes.Add(new Route("{resource}.css/{*pathinfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));

        routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;

        Data.DataContext context = new Data.DataContext();

        var AppRoutes = (from r in context.SomeRouteTable
                         select r).ToList();

        foreach (var AppRoute in AppRoutes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute(AppRoute.RouteName,
                                AppRoute.RouteUrl,
                                AppRoute.PhysicalFile, false);
            // The important part is the "false" above.  It is the 
            // CheckPhysicalUrlAccess parameter.
        }
    }
```

Now, in the web.config, an entry needs to be added:

```
<location path="landing"><system.web><authorization><allow users="*"/></authorization></system.web></location>
```

In the Application_Start void inside of the Global.asax file simply call the RegisterRoutes function:

```
this.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Restart your server, and done.  Now your route for the login page will work, however all of your other routes will be secure.  Should you need to expose another route all you have to do is add the base path of the route to your system.web authorization section with allow users="*".

The other thing that is in this, that will hopefully help others is the ability to take all of your javascript(js), images(psd, jpg, gif), really any static file out of the route handler.  All over the web, the .axd and .asmx were explained, however it was never in a location I could find how to also do this ignore for other static file types when dealing with routing in a webforms model.

I hope this helps somebody else, and saves them the time I spent in tracking all of this down and doing all of the unit testing myself.

Enjoy folks.

Comment: What's the namespace for Data.DataContext?